Laravel-excel returning blank page when I try to download
I 5 minute quick start guide for Laravel-Excel https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/
but it returns a blank page instead of the Excel file. My code looks almost identical to the site.
I'm running PHP 8.2, Laravel 11.5, and Laravel-Excel 3.1
EntriesExport
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Entry;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class EntriesExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function collection()
    {
        return Entry::all();
    }
}


In my controller:
public function export()
    {
        return Excel::download(new EntriesExport, 'entries.xlsx');
    }

In my routes:
Route::get('/entries/export/', [EntriesController::class, 'export'])->name('excel');


I got it working by changing the route from /entries/export/ to /xlsxexport. For some reason it doesn't work the way I had it. It's working now.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
